# Parts of a positive semidefinite

Tags: matrices

I have the following positive semidefinite matrix
\begin{align}
L=\left [
        \begin{matrix}
         A & \tau  \\
        \tau^T & p\\
        \end{matrix} 
\right ]>=0
\end{align}
What can be said about A ? Where $\tau $ is a vector and $p$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ itself must be positive semidefinite. Just consider $$\begin{pmatrix}v^t & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A & \tau \\ \tau^t & p \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}v \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ In general you'll find that $p\geq 0$ and $p A - \tau \cdot \tau^t \geq 0$.